# Hierarchy graph of parent-child node with multiple parents

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am plotting a logical topology using d3.js.I am using json to feed the graph.

Now I have a different scenario where I have to display hierarchy where a child node could have multiple parents. I searched through the examples available with d3 but I couldn't found solution.

Please suggest if anybody implement it. 
Thanks

Comment: I want plot something similar to [Multi-parent] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005850/directed-acyclic-graph-with-multi-parent-nodes)